# pyqt5 Is there a limit to loading widgets using clicked.connect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using the `QPushButton` to load the UI. `First -> Jumin -> Department -> next -> next` I want to create the UI in order. The problem is that I can not load the third Department into the QMainwindow window. I do not know why

When you create a widget in `QVBoxLayout`, it changes the size of the widget according to the wallpaper like `wxpython layout (wx.all)`. Can not change the `position (move)` and `size (resize)` by automatic centering?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.center_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.center_widget)
        self.FirstUI()

    def FirstUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton('test1', self)
        self.btn1.move(50, 50)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_click)

    def JuminUI(self):
        self.ju1 = QLineEdit('13')
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('^^^^^^^^^^')
        self.ju_text = QLabel('asd')
        self.jumim_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.jumim_layout.addWidget(self.ju_text)
        self.jumim_layout.addWidget(self.ju1)
        self.jumim_layout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.jumim_layout)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_click)

    def DepartmentUI(self):
        self.depart_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.depart_layout.addWidget(QPushButton('sdfsdf'))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.depart_layout)

    def btn1_click(self):
        self.btn1.deleteLater()
        self.JuminUI()

    def btn2_click(self):
        self.ju1.deleteLater()
        self.btn2.deleteLater()
        self.ju_text.deleteLater()
        self.DepartmentUI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fream = MainWindow()
    fream.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating and removing widgets is almost always a bad idea, and your code falls into those bad ideas, it's always best to hide the widgets and for that you should use the `QStackedWidget`, what `QStackedWidget` does is just make a widget visible on all widgets that you have been assigned by changing the `currentIndex`.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.center_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.center_widget)
        self.FirstUI()
        self.JuminUI()
        self.DepartmentUI()

    def FirstUI(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test1', widget)
        self.btn1.move(50, 50)

        self.center_widget.addWidget(widget)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(partial(self.center_widget.setCurrentIndex, 1))

    def JuminUI(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.ju1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('13')
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('^^^^^^^^^^')
        self.ju_text = QtWidgets.QLabel('asd')

        lay.addWidget(self.ju_text)
        lay.addWidget(self.ju1)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn2)

        self.center_widget.addWidget(widget)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(partial(self.center_widget.setCurrentIndex, 2))

    def DepartmentUI(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('sdfsdf'))

        self.center_widget.addWidget(widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    fream = MainWindow()
    fream.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```